# Passing an attribute to a view, default attribute not working

Tags: django, django-views

Here is my url :

```
  url(r'^test/$|test/(\d+)', views.test_page)
```

So with the django runserver fired I can enter 127.0.0.1:8000/test/ or
the same url followed with a "page" number.

Here is a simplified version of my view :

```
def test_page(request, pagenumber):
        paginator = Paginator(Test.objects.all(), 5)
        page = 1
        if pagenumber:
                page = pagenumber
        posts = paginator.page(page)
```

That works but is kinda inefficient. So I modified it to :

```
def test_page(request, page=1):
        paginator = Paginator(Test.objects.all(), 5)
        posts = paginator.page(page)
```

Which is nicer, works when I specify a page number in the url but when
I just enter 127.0.0.1:8000/test/ it doesn't. I got a :

```
Exception Type:         TypeError
Exception Value:       int() argument must be a string or a number,
not 'NoneType'
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/
paginator.py in validate_number, line 23
```

why doesn't the attribute page take the default value 1 when I don't
specify any page number ?

Answer (score 2):

For things like page numbers, it's better to use GET parameters, ie the form `/test/?page=1`. You do this directly in the view via `request.GET.get('page')`, so the urlconf is just `r'^test/$`.

Comment: Thanks. That's how I would do it in php but to me it really doesn't feel "Djangoish".

Comment: I disagree. Look for example at the admin app - pagination is controlled by GET parameters. Usually you find in a Django app that the main parameters are in the URL, and those that only affect display things like pagination are passed as GET params.

Comment: @burhan : Well that is how in the example they get the page variable but it is not "required" to get it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Do a check to see if the function parameter `page` is `None` in the code. If it is set the value to be 1. Instead of relying on the function to default it.

Comment: Yes that's what I did for the moment :
if not page:
     page=1
But still that's really strange to me. Setting a default parameter work with any python function, it's a mystery here why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen a url entry written that way.

Could you try something like:
To pass a named argument I think you have to specify that arguments name in your urls.py , it doesn't look like you're doing that now.

`(?P<page>\d+)/$` this is the way django recommends to pass defualt arguments. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#notes-on-capturing-text-in-urls

Comment: Thanks that makes me remember I forgot /$ at the end. But you are not required to pass ?P<page>, here my page variable in the view will take it directly.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
def test_page(request, **kwargs):
    page = kwargs.get('pagenumber', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(Test.objects.all(), 5)
    posts = paginator.page(page)
```

No shell around so I couldn't test this code.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not try to assign a default value to the argument "page" which you are passing in the function call. Just keep it as:

```
def test_page(request, page):
```

Please do try it, and write the url as:

```
url(r'^test/(?P<page>\d+)/$', views.test_page)
```

Comment: Thanks. Indeed it works if I don't set a default value but my question was why doesn't it work with it :)